# Publisher/Subscriber architecture with MassTransit

Tags: publish-subscribe, masstransit

Where can I find a working example of a publisher/subscriber setup using MassTransit ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the Grid.Distributor sample.

https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/tree/develop/src/Samples/Distributor

If you are using RabbitMQ instead of MSMQ, it is possible to use competing consumers. We don't recommend that with MSMQ though. If you want to try, it must be with transactional queues.

If you have more questions, feel free to reach out on the mailing list. http://groups.google.com/group/masstransit-discuss

Comment: The distributor sample does indeed work with the latest beta, and is included in the .ZIP if you download the entire package.